# How can I create CSS styles dynamically?

Tags: jquery, css

In this jQuery example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#empty-lists, they have CSS tags for each of the sortable ul's (sortable1, 2, and 3) like so:

CSS

```
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li { 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
    (...)
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class='dropfalse'>
    (...)
</ul>

<ul id="sortable3" class='droptrue'>
</ul>
```

The problem I'm having is that in my web page, I don't know ahead of time how many ul's i'll have. What's the best way to handle this without defining a every iteration of #sortable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to use separate ids for the CSS, you can use a single class instead:

CSS

```
.sortable li { 
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable1" class='sortable droptrue'>
    (...)
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class='sortable dropfalse'>
    (...)
</ul>

<ul id="sortable3" class='sortable droptrue'>
</ul>
```

The `droptrue` and `dropfalse` classes will still also work as expected.

Comment: This is the correct answer +1, however, I would just like to point out that sortable() requires IDs for some of it's functionality (specifically [toArray](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-toArray)), so it may be a good idea to leave those IDs in place.

Comment: @DerekHunziker Ahhh! I missed that part. Yes; the `sortable` ids should be left in place in this case. I'll edit!

Answer (score 2):

People seem to be forgetting the simple CSS3 method:

```
ul[id^=sortable] li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
```

We use the Attribute Starts With selector here. So this applies styling to any `li` elements inside any `ul` whose `id` attribute starts with the term `sortable`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/5THyv/).

Comment: I suspect using classes here would be faster (certainly more in line with the intent of CSS, methinks), but this is also good to know.

Answer (score 1):

@AndrewBarber's answer is the better way to approach things, but for the record, you *can* create CSS dynamically.

What you need to do is use some kind of server-side language (PHP is most popular, for whatever that's worth; ASP.NET, JSP, etc. are also used) to generate the CSS on the fly.

For example, you could use this HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.php">
```

And then have this for `stylesheet.php`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
    for ( $i = 1; $i < $sortableMax; ++$i )
    {
        echo <<<EOT
#sortable$i
{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
EOT;
    }
?>
```

This produces the following CSS, assuming `$sortableMax` was somehow set to `5`:

```
#sortable1
{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
#sortable2
{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
#sortable3
{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
#sortable4
{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `header('Content-Type: text/css');`.

Comment: @Purmou: Ah, good point. I would think that the `<link>` would tell the browser that already, but it's always good to be completely correct.